# error while deploying nuxt 3 in pre-rendered mode

Tags: vue.js, vite, nuxtjs3

Hi I'm trying to build my nuxt 3 app in pre-rendered mode (SSG mode), and I have add these configs in my `nuxt.config.ts` file

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },

  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      WEBSITE_NAME_EN: process.env.WEBSITE_NAME_EN,
      WEBSITE_ADDRESS: process.env.WEBSITE_ADDRESS,
      API_BASE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    },
  },

  ssr: true,
  nitro: {
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
    prerender: {
      crawlLinks: true,
    },
  },
  routeRules: {
    "/**": { swr: true },
    "/dashboard/**": { ssr: false },
  },
});
```

and my `package.json` file content

```js
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^5.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0",
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.8.0",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.11",
    "@types/node": "^18.16.19",
    "@vee-validate/rules": "^4.10.8",
    "@vime/core": "^5.4.1",
    "@vime/vue-next": "^5.4.1",
    "@vueuse/nuxt": "^10.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.6.5",
    "pinia": "^2.1.4",
    "sass": "^1.64.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "swiper": "^10.0.4",
    "v-lazy-image": "^2.1.1",
    "vee-validate": "^4.10.8",
    "vue-toastification": "^2.0.0-rc.5"
  }
}
```

but when I run `yarn build` command it produces these errors

```js
ℹ ✓ built in 7.26s                                                                                                                                                                                                            11:57:59 AM
✔ Server built in 7284ms                                                                                                                                                                                                      11:57:59 AM
✔ Generated public .output/public                                                                                                                                                                                       nitro 11:57:59 AM
ℹ Initializing prerenderer                                                                                                                                                                                              nitro 11:57:59 AM
ℹ Prerendering 1 initial routes with crawler                                                                                                                                                                            nitro 11:58:06 AM
  ├─ / (144ms) (Error: [404] Page not found: /http://localhost:8000)                                                                                                                                                     nitro 11:58:07 AM
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         nitro 11:58:07 AM
Errors prerendering:
  ├─ / (404)                                                                                                                                                                                                             nitro 11:58:07 AM
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         nitro 11:58:07 AM

 ERROR  Exiting due to prerender errors.                                                                                                                                                                                       11:58:07 AM

  at prerender (/E:/Workspace/personal-website-frontend-v2/node_modules/nitropack/dist/shared/nitro.1db3349c.mjs:189:11)
  at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at async /E:/Workspace/personal-website-frontend-v2/node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:2641:7
  at async build (/E:/Workspace/personal-website-frontend-v2/node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:3794:5)
  at async Object.invoke (/E:/Workspace/personal-website-frontend-v2/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/build.mjs:59:5)
  at async _main (/E:/Workspace/personal-website-frontend-v2/node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:49:20)

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have a 404 page at this address `/pages/404.vue` but it still gives me this error, so what is the problem and how can I fix it?

I couldn't find any answer, and the problem seems so weird to me

EDIT: I even made a new project and I add `nuxt.config.ts` content to that but still, the same error exist

Comment: Same problem happening to me...

Comment: @massimoi Please check the marked answer with the green tick, it might can solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem, there was no error about my `front-end` code, it was from my Laravel `back-end` API, I had set a `throttle` there for my API endpoints, so because of sending many requests I had take`404 and 429` errors so I comment `throttle` there and the problem got fixed

Note: if you don't know what `throttle` is, in Nutshall `throttle` is a request limiter in Laravel for instance when you send 10 requests in one minute it will limit you from the 11th request for some time.

Comment: how did setting throttle on a laravel based backend solve the building process of a nuxt spa frontend?

Comment: In SSG mode Nuxt tries to send requests for fetching all the routes content, e.g. imagine we have 200 routes that need to be fetched from API, so in SSG mode when all requests are sent, the `throttle` will throw an error, and not gonna let Nuxt to fetch all routes content, so build is gonna fail like this

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter is SSG or SSR mode when you send a lot of requests synchronously `throttle` will stop you from doing that and the build is gonna fail

Answer (score 7):

I've added `failOnError: false` to `prerender` object in `nuxt.config.ts` file and the build was successful but the error still exists and I couldn't find any answer for it.

Now my `nuxt.config.ts` content are like this:

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },

  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      WEBSITE_NAME_EN: process.env.WEBSITE_NAME_EN,
      WEBSITE_ADDRESS: process.env.WEBSITE_ADDRESS,
      API_BASE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    },
  },

  ssr: true,
  nitro: {
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
    prerender: {
      crawlLinks: true,
      failOnError: false, 
    },
  },
  routeRules: {
    "/**": { swr: true },
    "/dashboard/**": { ssr: false },
  },
});
```